# High definition video and native video calling in Nexus S

Tags: samsung-nexus-s

I try to compare Samsung Galaxy S with Nexus S.

1. May I know why video calling is not supported in Nexus S? Is it due to limitation in software or hardware?
2. May I know why high definition video is not supported in Nexus S? Is it due to limitation in software or hardware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where are you hearing this?  The Nexus S can absolutely support video chat, it has a front-facing camera.  Whether a video chat app supports the Nexus S is a different question.  Google Talk is supposed to support video chat in Honeycomb, hopefully it will be released for Gingerbread and support the Nexus S as well.

The Nexus S can't take HD video due to software restrictions, from everything I've read ([example](http://forum.xda-developers.com/showpost.php?p=10214742&postcount=1)).  I think it just wasn't prioritized since the Nexus S is a "developer phone".  (If you meant to ask if it can *play* HD video the answer is yes, depending on the format and such).